# Sending Dm to a user command in discord.py-rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I was trying to make a DM command which asks us which user we want to sent the DM message(value) to, ex- `!vx dm THIS IS THE CONTENT OF THE MESSAGE` will send a message to the author of the message asking - ""Whom Do you want to dm?" and the author will reply by mentioning the person whom he wants to send the dm to, and after doing so, it will send the DM to the user and then send a message saying "I have sent the message to X". This was how I wanted the command to be.

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, value):
    member = discord.Member if not discord.Member else discord.Member
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Whom do you want to send the message to?")
    def check(m):
        return m.content == member.mention == member
    await ctx.member.send(f"**{value}**")
    await ctx.member.send(f"||Sent by {ctx.author.mention} via VX Helper.||")
    e = discord.Embed(title=f"Message sent to {member.display_name}.", description=f"Message Content - {value}.", colour=0x40cc88)
    e.set_footer(text=f"Sent by {ctx.author.display_name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=3)
    await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

This code prints out this error in heroku -

```
2020-06-20T12:03:12.632899+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command dm:
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635752+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635825+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635826+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635861+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "run.py", line 336, in dm
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635862+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.member.send(f"**{value}**")
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635920+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'member'
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635960+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635963+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635963+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-06-20T12:03:12.635999+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636064+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636065+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636097+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 824, in invoke
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636098+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636131+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636132+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2020-06-20T12:03:12.636184+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'member'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ctx.author` not `ctx.member`. I highly recommend looking at the documentation

Comment: This `discord.Member if not discord.Member else discord.Member` also makes no sense.

Comment: I do not want to send the message to the author, I want it to send it to the user he mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, ideally, you should look to get the user input within the command. It will save you a headache with `wait_for`, although it would appear you have somewhat attempted to. Here is a simple way for you to use some code to send a message to whoever was mentioned.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, value):
    # Send a message to the mentioned user!
    await user.send(f"**{value}**")
    await user.send(f"||Sent by {ctx.author.display_name} via VX Helper.||")
```

So essentially, there are a couple of things to understand here. Firstly, we are parsing a `user: discord.User` argument, this is the person to send our message to. Using `: discord.User` simply means D.py will automatically convert it to a valid user, so we can send straight to that object.
The second thing to understand here is the usage of `*, value`. In simple terms, this means anything that comes after you mentioning the user will be put into a string for the `value` variable. You can read more about the logic behind that [here](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

After this, you can simply finish off your code however you want. I hope you found this helpful!